# Server refuses to boot when Raid5 disk is disconnected - /root/ missing

Tags: debian, raid, network-attached-storage

I recently set up a `NAS server` running a `Debian OS (6.0.4)`

It contains `4 disks`, `3` of them are in a `Raid5` array, while the last one is used for the OS.

To simulate a disk-failure I unplugged one of the raid disks, which resulted in the OS being unable to boot.

It started the boot, recognized that `md0` (the raid array) was running on `2/3` disks, and then threw a few errors.

It was unable to find the following directories:

```
/dev/root on /root,
/dev on /root/dev,
/sys on /root/sys,
/proc on /root/proc
```

It appears this happens regardless of which raid disk is removed. These directories are supposed to be on `/dev/sdd` my system disk.

Output from `fstab` and `blkid` :
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6017799/NASOutput.txt

If you need additional info, please let me know.

Comment: "and then threw a few errors" - you should state what these errors are. Diagnostic messages are useful when trying to diagnose a problem!

Comment: Sorry for not being specific - the errors it threw were "Directory not found" on the directories mentioned in the line below it.   I'm guessing the only reason it didn't boot was due to not being able to find those

Answer (score 2):

You take a disk out, and then the system fails to boot beyond loading the kernel. Once the kernel tries to find the filesystems it complains and drops you to a minimal shell. If it's something like that, then it's likely that grub(2) is not finding the root disk device. Because you took out a disk the device names have changed, what once was /dev/sdd could now be /dev/sdc.

It's possible you need to reconfigure grub(2) to use UUIDs instead of device names.

Although this seems at least a bit weird:

> It was unable to find the following directories. /dev/root on /root, /dev on /root/dev, /sys on /root/sys, /proc on /root/proc

Why would these directories be in the root home directory?
Those normally would be directly located on / (/dev et al). Did you create symlinks from /dev to /root/dev? if so, why?

Comment: I haven't created any symlinks to those directories, nor are they shown when i enter /root and look for them - not sure what that's all about :/     I suppose grub might be the reason behind it, so I'll try to investigate how to switch it to using UUIDs.

Comment: My grub2 .cfg file - it seems to be already implementing UUID? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6017799/Grubcfg.txt

Comment: It's set in /etc/default/grub, could you show contents of that file?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6017799/default-grub.txt

Comment: That looks fine, could you boot with a debian CD in rescue mode? Then choose the option to execute a shell in your systems root filesystem. Maybe you need to mount places such as /usr and /var. Then run "upgrade-from-grub-legacy", select your boot device (should be something like /dev/sdx, not a partition). When it's finished and reported no errors try a reboot. If it can't find the grub command you may have to source your .profile or .bash_profile in the /root (i.e. root's $HOME, command: source /root/.profile etc.).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - been a little busy over the weekend. I'll try out your suggestion as soon as I get home and report back.

Comment: I tried running the upgrade-from-grub-legacy command, and it seemed to do so successfully. It doesn't seem to have changed anything in terms of the issue when unplugging a disk though.

Comment: Well we eliminated one possible cause. Do you know if any directories in the root filesystem, such as /root, are symlinks from the raid partition? You know how you mentioned /root/dev, /root/proc etc.? Those should be located at /dev and /proc, NOT symlinks. Could you boot a CD and mount the root filesystem and do an "ls -al" of the mountpoint and show the output? Additionally remove /proc, /dev/, /sys and recreate them.

Comment: Would it be possible to change this line "set root='(hd3,msdos1)'" into something else using UUIDs?    The raid partition is mounted to a folder which I created, and should therefore not have any influence on the other folders, but I'll try what you suggested

Comment: As I am currently at work, I was only able to do an ls -al from the / directory after booting the OS.   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6017799/ls-alRoot.txt   Is that output of any use? Otherwise i might have to wait 'till I get back home.  How would I go about recreating the directories once removed?

Comment: Where did you get the line "set root='(hd3,msdos1)'" from, grub.cfg? I think that since you remove a disk it should be hd2 instead of hd3. Unless you put the disk back when you ran the upgrade-grub command, but then don't remove it when you boot. You just do mkdir /proc etc. to recreate those directories, though the output of your "ls -al" looks fine.

Comment: By the way, did you just successfully boot the OS?

Comment: The line is taken from the grub.cfg, yes - if I were to change hd3 to hd2, wouldn't that make it unable to boot with all raid disks attached?   - The OS should, preferably, be able to boot even if one of the raid disks fail, otherwise the data security from raid seems kinda wasted. Would it be possible to put somethint else instead of hd3, which would make it possible to identify the disk regardless of the number of disks plugged in?

Comment: Yes just leave hd3 as it is. As long as all disks are present it's fine.

Comment: Even if one of the disks fail, it should boot as long as it is connected?

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer because the discussion gets quite long.

I am still wondering about

> It was unable to find the following directories:
>
> /dev/root on /root,
>
> /dev on /root/dev,
>
> /sys on /root/sys,
>
> /proc on /root/proc

Why do you say /root/dev etc?
Are you just writing /root to indicate the root filesystem? That's something different than /root which is the home directory of the root account.

/dev, /sys and /proc should NOT be in /root.

If possible could you paste text or take a screenshot of the actual screen where the boot fails? So we can see more of the errors.

Update: Something must have caused your system to attempt to mount /proc, /dev/, /sys at the wrong place. You have to find out why. Do a "grep mount /etc/init.d" and carefully check the scripts it returns. In addition look at anything else /etc that might make your system mount these filesystems in the wrong place.

**You have to find out why your systyem tries to mount these filesystems in /root and fix that**

Comment: I'll add a screenshot once I get home - the directory it indicates the problem on is /root though (the home dir of Root)

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6017799/IMG_0075.JPG This is a link of the specific error during boot.

Comment: See my updated answer.